# Dropdown not loading in ReportViewer

Tags: ssrs-2008

Have a asp.net application for viewing the report from the SSRS Report Server using Report viewer control. Was using SSRS 2005. Now have upgraded to SSRS 2008 R2.  While using SSRS 2005 the Report Viewer Control in asp.net application was working fine. Now after upgrading, the Control are not loading properly like dropdown control is displayed with crossed icon (as if image not found) and navigation icons are not loaded.

But when we access the report server URL reports are getting displayed properly with proper icon display. Can any explain the resolution for this issue.

Environment Details

SQL SERVER Reporting Server 2008 R2
IE9
Windows 2008 R2

Comment: Did you rebuild your solution and/or project in Business Intelligence Development Studio and redeploy since upgrade?  Have you ensure your solution is not caching the old site data and remembering the cached settings now wrong?  Could you add another HTML Viewing site page if there is still an issue and confirm if error still exists with a new viewer on a new page as well?  There could possibly be a viewing issue with platform maybe.

Comment: have you try to load the report in IE ? Chrome ?